# Make all elements of array that are Hashable unique with a UUID hashValue?

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures, hashtable

I have an array of types that conform to `Hashable` these can be any type that conforms to hashable. The issue I'm having is that say I have an array of strings

```
let people = ["Joe", "Tom", "Bob", "Joe"]

if people[3] == people[people.firstIndex(of: "Joe")!]  {
    print(true) // Always true.
}
```

`Hashable` has `hashValue` which should be able to make these values unique, however, `hashValue` matches for values that are the same. Is there a way that I can extend `Hashable` so that every element conforming to it will get a `UUID()` assigned and therefore not identical to any others?

**Basically, is there a way to get `id: UUID` on everything that conforms to `Hashable`**

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't think you can -- but messing with the hash values of `String` and other basic types would break lots of stuff even if you could.

Comment: Adding a unique ID to all `Hashable` things that makes them not equal defeats the purpose of `Hashable` itself — which is to use the hash value of otherwise equal objects as a quick way of determining whether they could be equal. Have you considered storing custom structs, or even just `(String, UUID)` to distinguish between these values?

Comment: I think `(String, UUID)` is what I'm going to do after some more research. Seems like the most straight forward answer however will require an `O(n)` function to map the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do this a slightly different way. Could your array be of `Identifiable` instead? Then your example could be:

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

And each instance of `Person` will have a unique hashValue:

```
let people = [Person(name: "Joe"), Person(name: "Joe"), Person(name: "Joe")]
people.map(\.hashValue) // e.g. -> [7672515142881976808, -2470749298227582550, 3252810522385000211]
```